# Possible ways to scale Hue + HiveServer2 setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, bigdata, hadoop2, hue

We have a Hue + HS2 (Hive Server 2) setup on AWS which has been working fine up until about 80 users, but now we are seeing a lot of slowdown on HS2 side. We are looking into doing a horizontal scaling by adding one more Hue + HS2. But, I feel there maybe some scope for vertical scaling.

Does anyone know some good parameters to tinker with and what each one with fetch us in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hue HA is typically done with HTTPD, Apache or NGINX: http://gethue.com/automatic-high-availability-with-hue-and-cloudera-manager/

For HS2, we recommend HAProxy: http://gethue.com/how-to-optimally-configure-your-analytic-database-for-high-availability-with-hue-and-other-sql-clients/